# EAV load collection issue (High Load Time)

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, database, apache, eav-attributes

We have an eCommerce platform. The issue is that when we increased the products to ~3000, the EAV:load_collection is taking a lot of time(~20 sec) and eventually slowing the site. If I remove the products from the database, the site loads faster. Any inputs on reducing the time taken by EAV:load_collection would be highly appreciated

Comment: have you enable flat option from admin.?

Comment: Yes we have enable flat option for category as well as products configuration in setting

Comment: Additional MySQL instance information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size, # cores of your MySQL Host server 
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.